# Read contents of an array out of a Firebase / Firestore query

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi all I'm working with **Firebase - Firestore** for saving data. I just created a database call which returns me a `Date` from which I extract the **hours** and **minutes**.

The hours and minutes must be saved within an `array` with a tuple.

Everything seems to work but when I go to read my `array` outside of the clousure its value is always zero.

I need to read the contents of the `array` also outside the **Firestore** query method ..

Can anyone help me with this?

---

```
private var timeArray: [(Int, Int)] = []

private func getReservations() -> Void {

    Service.Database.reservationRoot.whereField("date", isGreaterThan: Date()).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, error) in
        
        guard error == nil else  { fatalError("Errore durante il recupero delle prenotazioni \(error!.localizedDescription)") }

        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            
            if let timestamp = document["date"] as? Timestamp {
                let hour = timestamp.dateValue().component(.hour)
                let minute = timestamp.dateValue().component(.minute)
                
                self.timeArray.append((hour, minute))

                // The array count is 2
                print(self.timeArray.count)
            }
        }
    }
   
    // The array count is 0
    print(self.timeArray.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
        
        if let timestamp = document.data()["date"] as? Timestamp {
            let hour = timestamp.dateValue().component(.hour)
            let minute = timestamp.dateValue().component(.minute)
            
            self.timeArray.append((hour, minute))
                            
        }
    }
```

Can you try this code

Comment: no but the problem is that the contents of the array are read only inside the for cicle `for document in querySnapshot!.documents` and not outside. I need to read the array values ​​outside the for cicle `for document in querySnapshot!.documents`